# How to handle multiple requests using HttpURLConnection in a MVC app?

Tags: java, http

I have a MVC application and I'd like that each request must handle its own session.

My request:

```
CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL));
URL url = new URL("http://google.com");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

As we know CookieHandler allow just one session per application. I'd like that each request creates and use its own session.

Does anybody know how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you will have to use Proxy while opening a connection...
the use of proxy provides always a new IP address for the server so you can be sure that the server maintains different session for each request...

your code will be something like following...

```
CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL));
URL url = new URL("http://google.com");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(new Proxy("some_proxy"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Pavan! This is a multithreaded application, it can have 100 requests and I want that each one to be handled with a independent session. 100 proxy, is that what you mean?